# Does $\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty }{ \frac { { 3 }^{ n }-{ 2 }^{ n } }{ { 4 }^{ n } }}$ converge?

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble with this particular series. It looks very similar to a geometric series, so I have tried comparing it to

$\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { 4 }^{ n } }  }$

but that doesn't help as that is convergent. I also thought it could possibly be transformed into a geometric series, but that would require factoring of the numerator, which I am unsure how to do. I have tried all the common tests but to no avail.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: If $a_m \to a$ and $b_m \to b$, then it's straightforward to show $a_m - b_m \to a - b$. In particular, if $a_m$ and $b_m$ are partial sums: $\sum_{n=1}^m (3/4)^n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^m (2/4)^n$, what does this say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{3^n-2^n}{4^n} = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n - \left(\frac{2}{4}\right)^n$

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
$$\sum_{ n=1 }^{ \infty }{ \frac { { 3 }^{ n }-{ 2 }^{ n } }{ { 4 }^{ n } }} = \sum_{ n=1 }^{ \infty }(3/4)^n - \sum_{ n=1 }^{ \infty }(1/2)^n.$$